# How to create the HMAC file with EasyRsa3?

Tags: openvpn

With the old version of Easy-RSA, I was using this way to create the HMAC file:

```
Openvpn—genkey—secret ta.key
```

However, I don't see the way to create this file with EasyRSA3. I al following this documentation: [EasyRsa3 documentation](https://Openvpn%E2%80%94genkey%E2%80%94secret%20ta.key)

Perhaps with the new versions of OpenVpn it is not needed to use HMAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're using was never part of EasyRSA at all – it's an OpenVPN command (you're literally running `openvpn`), as it deals with an OpenVPN-specific protocol extension and has nothing to do with standard TLS certificates that EasyRSA would handle.

So the command is still the same regardless of EasyRSA version. It may, however, differ between OpenVPN versions as latest releases are removing the old "static key" mode. The HMAC feature still remains but you might need to use `--genkey tls-auth` instead of `--genkey secret`.

> it is not needed to use HMAC?

Well, it was never *mandatory* to use it – "tls-auth" is an optional feature that OpenVPN offers on top of standard TLS (i.e. additional verification before TLS handshake even begins).